# InvalidRequestError thrown during unittesting of flask app

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I have built a large Flask app and have been running continuous unittests for a couple of years. Recently, I began to see the following error thrown:

```
InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush.
```

It appears that sqlalchemy is not properly releasing the session during teardown, which is strange since nothing in the app has changed? This is happening when I attempt to re-run the unittests and have the same unique entries into a database. For example, to test, I fill the database with test data which includes users (with unique emails, usernames); the first time I run the unittests it works, but fails on the second time.

This leads me to believe it is an issue with session teardown, which I don't understand well enough?

### Sample Unittest Code:

```
class CredentialsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app("testing")
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()

        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()

        Role.insert_roles()

        self.client = self.app.test_client(use_cookies=True)

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_auth(self):
        r = Role.query.filter_by(name="User").first()

        u = User(email="testemail@test.com", username="testuser", role=r)

        db.session.add(u)
        db.session.commit()
```

#### Config Settings

```
TESTING=True
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED=False
PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION=False
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='random-name-for-db.sqlite'
```

#### (Relevant) Requirements

- Flask (0.12.1)
- Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.1)
- SQLAlchemy (1.1.9)

If any other code would be relevant, I can add through an edit.

### Edit

Added full traceback. Also of note, the test DB is sqlite, whereas production is MySQL.

ERROR: test_authentication_protocols (test_api_1_0.CredentialsModelTestCase)

### Check authentication and credentials

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/tests/test_api_1_0.py" line 77, in test_authentication_protocols
    db.session.commit()
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 157, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 874, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 461, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 441, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2139, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2259, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in **exit**
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2223, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 389, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 548, in execute
    uow
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 181, in save_obj mapper, table, insert)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 835, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'test@user44457.com' for key 'ix_users_email'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO users (email, username, confirmed, _password_hash, otp_secr
et, member_since, last_seen, role_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ('test@user44457.com', 'testuser75', 1, 'pbkdf2:sha256:50000$zkYlgQKg$06b586db3c86c2bc5e3511b5710d9119ae65996
16d4785cd2d35e022b4152fea', 'WWGOWIJWJ7S4ZN3I', datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 10, 16, 42, 50, 115277), datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 10, 16, 42, 50, 115294), 3L)]

Comment: In your `setUp()` method, what happens if you query all your users right after the drop/create sentences? That should be empty. Also, it would be useful to see the complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: @Miguel It is empty if I query/print out all users right after that. Added full trace..

Comment: Your tests are going to your MySQL database somehow, not sqlite. Note the references to MySQL in the error text. Also, what you added does not look like the complete stack trace. There are no references to your source code in there.

Comment: @Miguel Oops. Reattached the entire traceback. I tried to check what you were saying by simply printing out the db object, which says the SQLAlchemy engine is the SQLite database and not the MySQL one. Is there a better way to check/debug that?

Comment: You can see in the full stacktrace that there are references to the MySQL driver (the lines that point to locations in `flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb`). So we know for a fact that your code is going to MySQL. Also, I'm pretty sure if you check your MySQL db you will find that the `test@testuser44457.com` entry exists, and if you remove it by hand the next test run will not error in the same way. Print the db object in file test_api_1_0.py line 77, right before the commit that errors to see what you get.

Comment: @Miguel Interesting. You are certainly correct that those entries are showing up in the MySQL local dev database, but when I print out the db object just before committing, I get the sqlite link `<SQLAlchemy engine='sqlite:////Users/dh/Documents/GitHub/web-tata/web-tata/test.db'>`. I mean, I can certainly hack this to get it to work, but it seems like there is something pretty strange going on..